# How to get proper contentHeight from WKWebView whenever getting updated web view scroll content size?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I have implemented WKWebView inside UITableViewCell. Initially I was tried with UITableView.automaticDimension for getting wrapped content height after loaded url into the web view. But seems getting content height only 44 pixel. So I have searched lot and tried with getting web view content height by using evaluateJavaScript with "document.readyState" also with "document.getElementById('svelte').scrollHeight" inside the ready state completion handler. This time used the "DivId = svelte" and got the exact contentHeight. Because If I try with "document.body.scrollHeight" etc,.. I'm getting height too big. So that's why I'm using "DivID" - I took reference from here: https://gist.github.com/pkuecuekyan/f70096218a6b969e0249427a7d324f91?permalink_comment_id=3642554#gistcomment-3642554

I got exact height as I said above on my command. But my problem is like once loaded the url into web view, in bottom side it having buttons like "+" symbol animating with wave. If click on that button, It will display the popup with additional information. So initially after loaded the url, web view getting height like "2025" then after clicked on buttons(+ symbol) after displayed popup with additional information means, this time web view scroll content size should be increased with 400 to 500 pixels. I need those information when the web view resized with additional content height. Kindly check the attached screen shots and my code too.[![After Initial loaded.[![Once clicked the plus symbol button. displayed popup with additional information. But UITableViewCell content height was not updated.[![This screen shot represent the popup with additional information. Becuase I have enabled scroll inside web view. But I'm expecting updated content height after done click action on button which is on back end side.

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        debugPrint("scroll view content size height on didFinish ==> \(webView.scrollView.contentSize.height) & webView Height => \(webView.bounds.height)")
        ///Regarding for zooming need to evaluate viewport java script.
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("var meta = document.createElement('meta');meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=YES, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);", completionHandler: nil)
        ///Regarding for getting dynamic height.
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
            if complete != nil {
                ///Getting height too big inside the UITableViewCells, the suggested solutions didn't work consistently. In my case querying specific div instead of the whole body seems to work fine. Thanks to this reference: https://gist.github.com/pkuecuekyan/f70096218a6b969e0249427a7d324f91?permalink_comment_id=3642554#gistcomment-3642554
                webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('svelte').scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
                    if let heightUW = height as? CGFloat {
                        RichContentTableViewCell.maximumHeight = heightUW
                    }
                    debugPrint("Error on document.getElementById div id -> svelte ==> \(String(describing: error))")
                })
            }
            debugPrint("Error on document.readyState ==> \(String(describing: error))")
        })
    }
```

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhF8D.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhF8D.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3pKj.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3pKj.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmuYx.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmuYx.jpg)

And also I have tried with "KVO" on WKWebView scrollView Content Size. This time Im getting exact height only If done scroll down and goto top on vertical scroll. Then only UITableViewCell updating with latest content height.

```
        webView.scrollView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)


    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if (object as? UIScrollView) == self.webView.scrollView, keyPath == "contentSize" {
            debugPrint("New contentSize height : %f", self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
            if RichContentTableViewCell.maximumHeight != self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height {
                RichContentTableViewCell.maximumHeight = self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
            }
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        self.webView.scrollView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", context: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the website you can update it by sending a post message with the the height you desire then update the tableViewCell

In the javascript file you will add this

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers.sendHeight.postMessage({height: 100})
```

and in the swift code you will implement this protocol [WKScriptMessageHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessagehandler)
then implement this function

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if message.name == "sendHeight" {
        guard let  dic = message.body as? [String:Any],
              let height = dic["height"] as? Int else {
                  return
              }
       // Update your cell height here
    } 
}
```